# Timing a gridView Update in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, autopostback

So I'm currently working with a `C#` `ASP` page in which I have a `DropDownList` and a `GridView`. I'm initializing both the GridView and the DropDownList (Along with their connected data sources) in the `PageLoad` event.

I've got the DropDownList set to `AutoPostback=true`. I'm changing the select statement for the GridView in the `DropDownList_SelectedIndexChanged` event. The end result is that the page loads again and then the select statement is changed, by which point the GridView has already loaded again. This basically means that it the GridView changes take two page refreshes to update.

Is there a way to avoid having to refresh the page twice? I tried simply updating the DataSource and the GridView in the Page_LoadComplete function instead but by that point it was too late to update the page this time around, meaning it still required another refresh.

Comment: do you have **ispostback** in your pageload ??

Comment: If not have a look at this article : **http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.ispostback.aspx**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you may try this in your page load....

```
    if(!IsPostBack)
    {
      // only then bind your grid View...
    }
```

and in your DDL's selectedindex changed event bind your grid to what ever select result set you may want to bind to...

what this will do is, your grid view bind code will get executed only for the first time in your page load event...and on any subsequent postbacks you may cause with your dropdown...you can bind your gridview in the selected index changed event...this will avoid binding your gridview twice...

Comment: Sure enough, after adding this in it works as desired. Thanks.